# BigDecimal symbols/parenthesis

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I'm trying force BigDecimal to use symbols (Ex. Instead of Decimal.multiply, do Decimal *), because of the mass parenthesis being involved in this problem.

Can you guys tell me if there's a way to use symbols on BigDecimal without converting it to Double or something? Or can you convert t into a format like term?

```
double t = ((1.00 / f1) * ((((4.00 / (ak1 + 1.00)) - (2.00 / (ak1 + 4.00))) - (1.00 / (ak1 + 5.00))) - (1 / (ak1 + 6.00))));
```

To a format like

```
term = ((one.divide(f,mc)).multiply(((((four.divide((ak.add(one)),mc)).subtract((two.divide((ak.add(four)),mc)))).subtract((one.divide((ak.add(five)),mc)))).subtract((one.divide((ak.add(six)),mc))))));
```

I've tried recording it lots of times, and spent almost 6 hours trying to figure out where I'm getting wrong with the BigDecimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. Since there is no operator overloading in Java.

To make things simpler for yourself write the equation out in parts and identity the bits that are complicated or repeated several times. Break up your computation into these parts and even write helper methods to help you get the sum computed. If you write the whole computation in parts then each part is easier to test.

eg.

```
import static java.math.BigDecimal.ONE;

public class Sum {

    private static final TWO = new BigDecimal("2");
    private static final FOUR = new BigDecimal("4");
    private static final FIVE = new BigDecimal("5");
    private static final SIX = new BigDecimal("6");

    private BigDecimal f;
    private BigDecimal ak;

    private MathContext mc;

    public Sum(BigDecimal f, BigDecimal ak, MathContext mc) {
        this.f = f;
        this.ak = ak;
        this.mc = mc;
    }

    public BigDecimal calculate() {

        return inverse(f).multiply(
            firstSubtractRest(
                xOverYPlusZ(FOUR, ak, ONE),
                xOverYPlusZ(TWO, ak, FOUR),
                xOverYPlusZ(ONE, ak, FIVE),
                xOverYPlusZ(ONE, ak, SIX),

            ));

    }

    private BigDecimal inverse(BigDecimal x) {
        return ONE.divide(x, mc);
    }

    /* returns x / (y + z) */
    private BigDecimal xOverYPlusZ(BigDecimal x, BigDecimal y, BigDecimal z) {
        BigDecimal divisor = y.add(z);
        return x.divide(divisor, mc);
    }

    private BigDecimal firstSubtractRest(BigDecimal... values) {
        BigDecimal value = values[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
            value = value.subtract(values[i]);
        }
        return value;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot, but my parentheses are still wrong. But this way of solving the problem would be easier to fix the parentheses though.

Answer (score 4):

No. [Unfortunately](http://james-iry.blogspot.com/2009/03/operator-overloading-ad-absurdum.html) Java does not support operator overloading. You have no choice but to use those methods on `BigDecimal`.

Comment: What about having it to reduce the amount of parenthesis involved in it? Is the only way to solve that by making a method for the BigDecimal methods?

Comment: @Peter You can break your long formula into smaller chunks, and process them with separate commands. It will increase the number of lines, but it will make your code way more readable.

Comment: @Peter: What Laf said. I am afraid that's the only way to go about this.

Comment: Alright I'll try that, and if it's taking too long, or more confusing, I'll just do what Dave said.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a simple parser to build the expression then evaluate it using [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) or other scripting engine available inside Java code.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of inverting f1 first, you could simply the expression by placing it last.

```
double t = (4 / (ak1 + 1) - 2 / (ak1 + 4) - 1 / (ak1 + 5) - 1 / (ak1 + 6)) / f1;
```

Are you sure you need the accuracy BigDecimal provides. i.e. you need more than 15 digits of precision.

```
double f1 = 1;
double ak1 = 1;

double t = (4 / (ak1 + 1) - 2 / (ak1 + 4) - 1 / (ak1 + 5) - 1 / (ak1 + 6)) / f1;

System.out.println(t);

System.out.println(new Sum(BigDecimal.ONE, BigDecimal.ONE, MathContext.DECIMAL64).calculate());
System.out.println(new Sum(BigDecimal.ONE, BigDecimal.ONE, MathContext.DECIMAL128).calculate());
```

prints

```
1.2904761904761906
1.2904761904761904
1.2904761904761904761904761904761904
```

If you need more than 15 digits of accuracy, you need BigDecimal. But if you are trying to simplify your code and don't need so much precision, I would just use `double`.